# Javascript, unable to parse XML child nodes

Tags: javascript, xml

i've some troubles while parsing a xml response in my Javascript code (using extjs 4, but i think it doesn't matter here).

The xml response is something like this:

```
<response>
  <id>9</id>
  <time>2012-05-24 14:22:44</time>
  <name>user</name>
  <message>message</message>
  <p2pchat>
    <requestor>user1</requestor>
    <requested>user2</requested>
    <time>2012-05-26 12:13:28</time>
    <message>msg</message>
  </p2pchat>
</response>
```

I've no troubles parsing the 1st level elements like id, time, name and message, but my js code can't access the deeper ones. The code is:

```
var response = xmlHttpGetMessages.responseText;
response = xmlHttpGetMessages.responseXML.documentElement;
idArray = response.getElementsByTagName("id");
nameArray = response.getElementsByTagName("name");
timeArray = response.getElementsByTagName("time");
messageArray = response.getElementsByTagName("message");

requestorsArray = response.getElementsByTagName("p2pchat/requestor");
requestedsArray = response.getElementsByTagName("p2pchat/requested");
timep2pArray = response.getElementsByTagName("p2pchat/time");
messagep2pArray = response.getElementsByTagName("p2pchat/message");
```

After this code executes, the length of the four last arrays is always 0, nothing has been fetched from my xml response.
I've searched google for a way to parse inner elements in a xml tree but in 10 different pages i've found almost 10 different sintaxs, none seemed to work for me..any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of hours of data mining on google gived me the solution, i post it here so if someone encounters the same problem and finds this post has the solution i used:

```
var xmlp2pchat = response.getElementsByTagName("p2pchat");

var requestorsArray = Array();
var requestedsArray = Array();
var timep2pArray = Array();
var messagep2pArray = Array();

for(var i=0;i<xmlp2pchat.length;i++) {
  var x = xmlp2pchat[i].getElementsByTagName("requestor");
  var y = xmlp2pchat[i].getElementsByTagName("requested");
  var z = xmlp2pchat[i].getElementsByTagName("time");
  var t = xmlp2pchat[i].getElementsByTagName("message");

  for(var j=0;j<x.length;j++) {
    requestorsArray.push(x[j]);
    requestedsArray.push(y[j]);
    timep2pArray.push(z[j]);
    messagep2pArray.push(t[j]);
  }

}
```

And then i use it with

```
 var whatever = requestorsArray[i].firstChild.data
```